# Neovim: fold code with `foldmethod=syntax` or `foldmethod=expr` depending on Tree-sitter

Tags: neovim, code-folding, treesitter

I've just fresh-installed [LazyVim](https://www.lazyvim.org/) and I'm having troubles configuring code folding to my liking.

- For the languages for which I have no [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) parser installed I would like to use `:set foldmethod=syntax` (presumably Neovim already knows how to parse these languages at a basic level).
- On the other hand, for the languages for which I have a [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) parser installed and configured I would like to use `:set foldmethod=expr foldexpr=nvim_treesitter#foldexpr()`.

The reason for this is that in both circumstances if I use the opposite configuration then code folding will not work at all.

My idea is to default to `:set foldmethod=syntax` and have an [autocommand](https://neovim.io/doc/user/autocmd.html) switch it to `expr` when opening a buffer with [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) support, however I have no idea how to achieve that (I don't know what event to listen to and how to detect whether a [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) parser gets loaded for the current buffer). Maybe there is some other way to achieve this, by directly configuring [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter) to do the switching; I don't know.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: neovim/vi/vim questions should be asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there.

Answer (score 0):

In your LazyVim config, under `lua/config/autocmds.lua`, you can add:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "FileType" }, {
  callback = function()
    if require("nvim-treesitter.parsers").has_parser() then
      vim.opt.foldmethod = "expr"
      vim.opt.foldexpr = "nvim_treesitter#foldexpr()"
    else
      vim.opt.foldmethod = "syntax"
    end
  end,
})
```

This follows the general format recommended in LazyVim's [tips section](https://www.lazyvim.org/configuration/tips).

Note that, as recommended in the [nvim-treesitter README](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter), you may also want to set this elsewhere:

```
set nofoldenable   " Disable folding at startup.
```

... though I found it unnecessary, as files open without folds anyway in my LazyVim config.

Note that this won't trigger for new, unnamed buffers. If you wanted to handle that explicitly you could trying handling the `BufEnter` event instead of `FileType`, or have a look at other event types via `:help events` inside Neovim.